# Java Enum - Store Type For Later Cast

Tags: java, class, types, casting, enums

I have an enum representing all column values in a specific table. Now I want to store a type per enum element which is queried for later casting.

```
public enum Value {

    MEMBER1(?...?),
    MEMBER2(?...?);

    private final ?...? type;

    Value(?...? type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public ?...? getType() {
        return type;
    }

}
```

I don't now what I have to put instead of `?...?`. Maybe its `MyClassA.class` and `Class` but how can I use this value for this operation:

```
MEMBER1.getType() instance = (MEMBER1.getType()) object;
```

This is really important for database communication with java, for me.

**UPDATE: I mean this operation.**

END UPDATE: There was is logic error. If I knew the different types I can simply create multiple methods because I have a api specification.

Comment: "*how can I use this value for this operation: `MyClassA instance = (MEMBER1.getType()) object;*`" do you know that you want to create variable of type `MyClassA`? How are you later going to use this variable? Why do you need its proper type?

Comment: Also look at java.sql.Types and javax.sql.rowset.RowSetMetaDataImpl#getColumnClassName mapping. Maybe it will be enough for you.

Answer (score 7):

You are right. The enum should be defined as follows

```
public enum Value {

   MEMBER1(String.class),
   MEMBER2(Integer.class);

   private final Class<?> type;
   private Value(Class<?> type) {
       this.type = type;
   }

   public Class<?> getType(){
       return this.type;
   }
}
```

The second part is actually something you don't want to do because you already know what is the type you want to cast your object to (In your case is it MyClassA) so you can cast directly like following

```
//I know what is the target type so I don't have to fetch the type from my enum
MyClassA instance = (MyClassA) object;
```

Once you will need to build your logic on unknown data type, than you can do something like

```
Object o = getTheObjectSomewhere();
if(o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MEMBER1.getType()){
    String s = (String) o;
    System.out.println("Target type is string!");
    doSomething();
} else if (o.getClass().isAssignableFrom(MEMBER2.getType()){
    Integer i = (Integer) i;
    System.out.println("Target type is integer!");
    doSomethingElese();
}
```

Maybe you want to search the column later according to the type of your object. Then you can create a method to get the column

```
public Value getColumnByObjectType(Object o){
    for(Value v : Value.values()){
        if(v.getType().equals(o.getClass()){
            return v;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

And use it to search for the column

```
Object o = getObjectSomewhere();
Value column = getColumnByObjectType(o);
```

To get the user object according to the comment bellow you can do something like following using JPA

```
public Object getUserObject(int id, Value v){
    TypedQuery<?> q = DBUtils.getEntityManager().createQuery("select u.:column from User u where u.id = :id",v.getType());
    q.setParameter("column", v.toString());
    q.setParameter("id", id);
    q.setMaxResult(1);
    return q.getSingleResult();
}
```

Comment: Yes I know the class i want cast to. But this information has to be stored in the enum member.

Comment: Maybe can you specify where you get your object from and why you need to store the type inside the enum?

Comment: I want to get an value of a user stored in database like: "getUserData(6, Value.NAME)". 6 is the id and it should returns an instance of the class referenced in the enum member NAME.

Answer (score 4):

You could do it by storing the Class of the object and use it to cast when necessary:

```
class Test {

    public static void main(String[] arguments) throws Exception {
        Object object = new MyClassA();
        Class<MyClassA> clazz = Value.MEMBER1.getType();
        MyClassA instance = clazz.cast(object);
        System.out.println(instance);
    }

}

enum Value {

    MEMBER1(MyClassA.class),
    MEMBER2(MyClassB.class);

    private final Class<?> clazz;

    Value(Class<?> clazz) {
        this.clazz = clazz;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public <T> Class<T> getType() {
        return (Class<T>) clazz;
    }

}

class MyClassA { }
class MyClassB { }
```

Comment: While this will compile and will work after a fashion, this is still unsafe.  The `@SuppressWarnings` is arguably improper because there is no logic present that guarantees that the cast will be safe or that a ClassCastException won't occur.

Answer (score 0):

> how can I use this value for this operation:

```
MyClassA instance = (MEMBER1.getType()) object;
```

Use **instanceof** to check object type.

```
MyClassA instance;
if (object instanceof MyClassA && object instanceof MEMBER1.getType()){ 
 instance = (MyClassA) object;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have an enum representing all column values in a specific table. Now
>   I want to store a type per enum element which is queried for later
>   casting.

In general, this can't be done the way you want it to be done.

What you want is for the enum to hold the keys for a *heterogenous type safe container* (Essential Java, 2nd Ed.).

Unfortunately, Java Class objects are generified (eg. `String.class` is `Class<String>`) and *Java enums and generics do not play well together*.

While it is possible to store a Class object as a field within an enum, your Class object will lose its type information in the process.  You will still need to manually reassert the type linkage when you access the field ... and this will require an unsafe cast.  I don't know that there is any way around it.

For example, your enum may have a field named `colClassToken` in which you intend to store the type of the associated column in your table:

```
public enum TableColumn {
    MEMBER1(String.class),
    MEMBER2(Integer.class);

    private Class<?> e_colToken;

    TableColumn(Class<?> tok) { this.e_colToken = tok; }

    public Class<?> getColumnToken() { return this.e_colToken; }

    :
    :
}
```

What you would like to be able to do now is use the Class object's `cast()` method to reassert the type linkage when you access columns in your table (for example, using an idiom like):

```
String myColumn = MEMBER1.getColumnToken().cast(myTable.getCol(MEMBER1));
```

This won't compile, however.  Because the type of the Class object has been lost in the enum field (and because you cannot generify an enum), the compiler is unable to guarantee the type safety of the `cast()` operation.